# SQL Server - Index Seek: count of operation

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, performance

In SQL Server we have `Index Seek` operator. Which works very well for a search operation.

How much operation SQL Server needs to perform in order to get a value? I assume that it should be the height of the tree.

Comment: Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody can say the one answer for sure because it depends on many parameters :

1. Index type (Clusted, None Clustered)
2. Unique or Not
3. Null or Not Null
4. Expected rows stored in which page

So, there is the well-explained article about index seeking [O2] blow:

https://sqlserverfast.com/epr/index-seek/